# Matching function name and arguments using regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I have some strings in the following pattern

```
'walkPath(left, down, left)'
```

To extract the function name alone, and the arguments in an another array, i used those regular expressions:

```js
const str = 'walkPath(left, down, left)'

const functionNameRegex = /[a-zA-Z]*(?=\()/
console.log(str.match(functionNameRegex)) //outputs ['walkPath'] ✅✅

const argsRegex = /(?![a-zA-Z])([^,)]+)/g
console.log(str.match(argsRegex)) //outputs [ '(left', ' down', ' left' ]
```

the first one worked fine. In the second regex, the '(' from from '(left' should be excluded, so it should be 'left'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one:

```js
/(?<=\((?:\s*\w+\s*,)*\s*)\w+/g
```

```js
const str = 'walkPath(left, down, left)'

const functionNameRegex = /[a-zA-Z]*(?=\()/
console.log(str.match(functionNameRegex))

const argsRegex = /(?<=\((?:\s*\w+\s*,)*\s*)\w+/g
console.log(str.match(argsRegex))
```

It is not very restricted, if you really want to be safe, you can try:

[`/(?<=\w+\s*\((?:\s*\w+\s*,\s*)*\s*)\w+(?=\s*(?:\s*,\s*\w+\s*)*\))/g`](https://regex101.com/r/9VYA5t/3)

Comment: I'm going to accept this one because it has less lines of code, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Use this regular expression for getting the arguments:

```
const argsRegex = /\(\s*([^)]+?)\s*\)/
```

For getting the arguments in an array:

```
const str = 'walkPath(left, down, left)'
const argsRegex = /\(\s*([^)]+?)\s*\)/
let res = str.match(argsRegex)
let args = res[1].split(", ")
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but it did not work, the arguments should be in an array like ['left', 'down', 'left']

Comment: @FayezNazzal I had updated the code to get the arguments in an array.